# ASP.NET Custom authorization module for files download

Tags: asp.net, file, download, authorization

In an ASP.NET 3.5 application I have the following scenario:

The users can create folders where they can upload files. The files are stored on the server's file system and can be downloaded then by requesting URLs with the format:

hostname/UsersFolders/**User1/Folder1**/requested_file_name.jpeg,

The problem is that I want that only **User1** and the other users to whom **User1** granted access, to be able to download the files located in **Folder1** and not any other user.

I've already implemented the business logic for the n - n relation between users and folders and now I'm just trying to authorize the requests to the files located in the folder named **UsersFolders** and to grant or deny access depending on which user requests which folder. **What's the best approach to do this?**

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can obtain more or less the same result as writing a **HttpModule** by simply checking URL for each request in **global.asax** during **Authenticate_Request** event. As the **HttpModules are instantiated for every request**, the disadvantage of this approach would be the fact that I have to call the authorization method for absolutely every incoming request to my application no matter if the requested resource is public(ex. *.js/*.css files) or not.

I consider a better approach writing a HttpHandler named for instance **MyHttpHandler** and placing the corresponding configuration file in the folder **UsersFolders** as described below:

```
<system.web>
  <httpHandlers>
    <add  verb="GET" path="*" type="MyHttpHandler" />
  </httpHandlers>
</system.web>
```

In this way **the handler is instantiated only when a file from UsersFolder** is requested.

Comment: Instantiating handler is not such a big deal as you think. Handler is just an object of specific class. Hundreds of objects are being instantiated for each request. It's not an issue.

Answer (score 0):

I would probably write an [HTTPModule like this](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/307996), inspect the incoming request. If the URL request is for a child of "UsersFolder" then compare the authenticated user's credentials to the requested user folder. Return a HTTP error code 401 if they shouldn't have access.

[More info about HttpModules](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zec9k340%28VS.85%29.aspx).

Comment: Is it possible to configure the module for a certain folder so that it's not executed for absolutely every request?